# here Payment has association with payee or Payment has association with User I am confused?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

class Payment < ApplicationRecord 
belongs_to :payee, class_name: "User"
end 
class User<ApplicationRecord
has_many :received_payments, foreign_key: 'payee_id', class_name: 'Payment'
end

Comment: What is your database schema, what do you mean by payee and user? are they separate  or only one model, if they are separate, why are you using 'User' model for payee ? Be more specific about your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the `payments` table has a column `payee_id` which is nothing but a foreign key to the table `users`

So your association is setup in a way that

1. Every Payment belongs to an User and
2. Every User could have multiple Payments

Answer (score 0):

A `Payment` belongs to a `User` through a convenience method called `payee`.

A Standard rails ORM association would look like this

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

in this case the association will assume the `user` refers to the `User` model and the `users` table and that the `payments` table has a column called `user_id` to facilitate this relationship.

Your model is set up to use `payee` instead likely because `payment.user` does not read as naturally or make as much logical sense as `payment.payee` (also possible payment has a `payer` as well).

To set up this relationship it would look like this:

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :payee
end
```

Now the association will assume the `payee` refers to  the `Payee` model and the `payees` table and that the `payments` table has a column called `payee_id` to facilitate this relationship.

However in your case the "payee" is a `User` (not a `Payee`) so we need to inform the association of this conventional deviation, resulting in:

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :payee, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Now the association has been told the `payee` refers to the `User` model and the `User` and the table named `users` (based on `User.table_name`) but it will join to this table using a column name based on the association name (`payee`) so it will still use the column named `payee_id` to facilitate this relationship.